# ironpython doesn't create csv in web service

Tags: c#, web-services, ironpython

Normally, I run my ironpython and it makes csv file but when i put it in web service there is no csv in the folder (it actually appears when running the program). These are my codes example.

```
bool success = false;

    //c# call python to do csv file
     IDictionary<string, object> options = new Dictionary<string, object>();
     options["Arguments"] = new[] { receivedata };
     var engine = Python.CreateEngine(options);
     var scope = engine.CreateScope();
     var script = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(@"PartToPython");
     script.Execute(scope);
     success = true;
     return success;
```

Comment: We can't comment on this, it lacks too much information. Best guess: the script writes to the current directory, which is going to be `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\` or `C:\Windows\System32` or something like that.

Comment: Sorry for lacking information but I don't have any ideas which information you want . So please tell me. I'm new in coding. I've already check the directory you mentioned but there is none. And I've test the time between normal ironpython program and through web service , it takes the same. So I can make sure that the web service work normal but why csv do not create.

Comment: It _does_ create the CSV, just not in the place you're expecting it to. First of all, you can inspect the code that actually writes the file, and the output of `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`.

Comment: I got it!. Thanks a lot CodeCaster ^^.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i've already found my csv it placed in IIS express folder in drive C but i have no idea why.